# E2E testing multiple posibilities with exception

Tags: kotlin, e2e-testing, junit5

i have a problem that i don't exactly know how to solve. I'm implementing an E2E test in which using selenium i need to click in a Link and check that is sending me to the right URL.

Here starts the problem...

There are 3 possibilities, mix of 2 types of links, just one type of link or the other type of link. No problems with the situations in which there are both types of links but when there is just one type when it searches for the identifier we use for the links that are not in page it gives me a timeoutException. This is not a failure because it's a posible situation but i will like to know if there is a way in which to check that if it finds no links it asserts that the exception is thrown.

I though using a runCatching (or try catch) wait for the link to appear and if it doesn't appear the test asserts that when i look for the element the timeout exception is thrown again.

It smells a bit for me this way of doing it and i don't know if it's correctly done.

EDIT: Im ussing AssertK and JUnit5 for testing.

EDIT 2: I've done this, i dont know if it a correct way of doing it

```
runCatching {
            driver.waitFor(numberOfWidgetsToBeMoreThan(BrowserSelector.cssSelector(OFFERS_WITH_PRICE_AND_DATE), 0), ofMillis(2000))
        }.onFailure {
            assertThrows<WaitTimeoutException> {
                findLink(OFFERS_WITH_PRICE_AND_DATE)
            }
        }.onSuccess {
            val widget = findLink(OFFERS_WITH_PRICE_AND_DATE)
            widget.click()
            assertThat(driver.url).contains(NO_DATE_TEXT)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your problem correctly, but you can use [assertFails](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/kotlin.test/assert-fails.html) to assert that a piece of code throws an exception:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val exception = assertFails {
        // some code that should throw
    }
    // some more assertions on the type of exception etc. may go here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! the thing is that i dont know if its going to fail or not because it depends of the database. And that there are no links is not exactly a fail.